# Real time example for Latent defects and regression defects

Tags: terminology

Can anyone explain Latent defects and regression defects
With real time examples in the software

Answer (score 1):

**Latent defects:**

[What is a latent bug?](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/q/9170/40022)

So latent defects **are undisclosed or undiscovered defects in a system**, mostly corner case scenarios ([Difference between Corner Case Testing, Boundary Case Testing and Edge Case Testing](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/42941/difference-between-corner-case-testing-boundary-case-testing-and-edge-case-test)). This is because corner cases are hard to be detected due to high numbers of valid usecases (Exhaustive testing is not possible; an important principle of testing) and are only observed when the corner case is encountered accidently by some user.

example consider a Sum() function that fails to print the result 190924.989. This issue will be exposed only when someone tries a calculation that may end up in 190924.989.

**Regression defects:**

The product was working fine until some changes made to a module.

**Example:**

consider a Sum() function that fails to print the result 190924.989, but was functioning properly until changes where made to the print() module inside the Sum().

**Tips:**

There are tons of overlaping between words in software testing, these terms are just there to make focused comments on issues so try to get familiar but don't need to get indepth understanding and end yourself confused. So normal defects are defects found during testing, missed defects are usually those defects which could have been found earlier but got pushed to production, Latent defects are severe hard to find defects in legacy/or new products that was hit during corner cases.